# Correct scope of using using

Tags: c#, scope, using-statement

I'm in a quarrel with a colleague regarding the appropriate scope of the *using* statement. This is the method in question.

```
public Guid IsServerReachable()
{
  try
  {
    WhoAmIResponse whoAmI;
    using (OrganizationServiceProxy service = GetService())
      whoAmI = service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest()) as WhoAmIResponse;
    return whoAmI.UserId;
  }
  catch { return Guid.Empty; }
}
```

One of us claims that the *using* statement should include the declaration of *whyAmI*, while the other argues that it's only the *service* instance that needs to be using-ified. I'm not telling which is my theory but one is clearly wrong. Which?

Comment: The OrganizationService will be disposed (if it implments IDisposed) but it WhoAmI references OrganizationService. Therefore you won't get anything returned since it has been disposed of! You would need the return within the using statement.

Comment: If the entire scope of variable whoAmI is the using block (missing parentheses confuse things here a bit), it won't even exst when the `return whoAmI` is executed.

Comment: I'm not seeing how it matters here, if you include all three lines (declaration, assignment, and return)

Comment: @KonradViltersten Sorry, it was a response to Dave suggesting that the `whoAmI` object is the one that gets disposed (his comment was removed). I'll delete my comment (no point to have it there anymore!)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Exactly what I was about to type before I decided to refresh one more time ;) However, if `WhoAmIResponse` implements `IDisposable` and should be disposed of, then the value of `UserId` should be copied to a variable of its type and used as the return value, and `WhoAmI` should be declared in it's own `using` statement within the other `using` block.

Comment: Actually, I have a bigger quarrel with your use of `as` in this case. If the resultant value of `service.Execute` doesn't actually return the correct type (for whatever reason or future bug), it will throw a `NullReferenceException` later rather than the more correct `InvalidCastException` earlier where the real problem lay. Catching all exceptions and swallowing them without logging is another big issue (but I'm guessing the _actual_ code you have doesn't do that, right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (OrganizationServiceProxy service = GetService())
    whoAmI = service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest()) as WhoAmIResponse;
```

Will be equivalent to:

```
OrganizationServiceProxy service = GetService();
try
{
    whoAmI = service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest()) as WhoAmIResponse;
}
finally
{
    if (myRes!= null)
        // Call the object's Dispose method.
        ((IDisposable)service).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Not quite; I'm pretty sure the `GetService()` assignment happens _within_ the `try` so if there's an exception on the thread _before_ it enters the `try/finally` block, it will still dispose. EDIT: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2732078/1269654

Comment: Shouldn't the declaration of *service* also be inside *try*?

Comment: @KonradViltersten If you did that, you wouldn't be able to dispose it in the finally block (because it wouldn't be accessible in that scope) Declare it outside, assign it inside.

Answer (score 6):

Both is correct. I tend to write this:

```
public Guid IsServerReachable()
{
    try
    {
        using (OrganizationServiceProxy service = GetService())
        {
            WhoAmIResponse whoAmI = service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest()) as WhoAmIResponse;
            return whoAmI.UserId;
        }
    }
    catch { return Guid.Empty; }
}
```

This does not have any influence on whether `whoAmI` is disposed of - the only thing getting automatically disposed of is `service`.

If `WhoAmIResponse` was also an `IDisposable`, you'd have to write the following to automatically release both:

```
    using (OrganizationServiceProxy service = GetService())
    using (WhoAmIResponse whoAmI = service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest()) as WhoAmIResponse)
        return whoAmI.UserId;
```

Comment: I have a pair of very strong reasons to use the method with *whoAmI* declared outside the scope of *using*, so unless it's plain wrong (which you say that it isn't), I'll go with that. Thanks.

Comment: Out of interest: what a your reasons? I have some very strong reasons for what I'm writing :-D

Comment: From an IL perspective, the only difference is either the `OrganizationalServiceProxy.Dispose` gets called _before_ the access of the `WhoAmIResponse.UserId` property (this is your code posted) or the Dispose gets called _after_ the property access (everything bound by the `using` block as posted in this answer). If that doesn't matter, then go with what is more readable/easier for your team. If it does matter (say with NHibernate lazily loaded collections) then the answer is pretty clear which you should go with (only one way works!).

Answer (score 4):

Since the declaration of `whoAmI` doesn't really make any difference anything in terms of performance/scoping in this case. All it really comes down to is should the property access of `whoAmI.UserId` also be included in the `using`. From an IL perspective, the only *functional* difference between the two is the order in which the `OrganizationalServiceProxy.Dispose` method is invoked and when the `WhoAmIResponse.UserId` is accessed.

(EDIT: I don't think there's any real issue with how the `try/catch` is handled to return a default value, and that doesn't seem to be part of the question, so this is also omitted)

In your posted code (simplified to make the IL clearer):

```
public Guid IsServerReachableOutsideUsingScope()
{
    WhoAmIResponse whoAmI;
    using(var service = new Service())
        whoAmI = service.Execute();
    return whoAmI.UserId;
}
```

Results in IL of:

```
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+Service..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.1     // service
IL_0006:  ldloc.1     // service
IL_0007:  callvirt    UserQuery+Service.Execute
IL_000C:  stloc.0     // whoAmI
IL_000D:  leave.s     IL_0019
IL_000F:  ldloc.1     // service
IL_0010:  brfalse.s   IL_0018
IL_0012:  ldloc.1     // service
IL_0013:  callvirt    System.IDisposable.Dispose
IL_0018:  endfinally  
IL_0019:  ldloc.0     // whoAmI
IL_001A:  callvirt    UserQuery+WhoAmIResponse.get_UserId
IL_001F:  ret
```

Whereas declaring everything within the using block:

```
public Guid IsServerReachableWithinUsingScope()
{
    using(var service = new Service())
    {
        WhoAmIResponse whoAmI = service.Execute();
        return whoAmI.UserId;
    }
}
```

Produces IL:

```
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+Service..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.0     // service
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     // service
IL_0007:  callvirt    UserQuery+Service.Execute
IL_000C:  stloc.1     // whoAmI
IL_000D:  ldloc.1     // whoAmI
IL_000E:  callvirt    UserQuery+WhoAmIResponse.get_UserId
IL_0013:  stloc.2     // CS$1$0000
IL_0014:  leave.s     IL_0020
IL_0016:  ldloc.0     // service
IL_0017:  brfalse.s   IL_001F
IL_0019:  ldloc.0     // service
IL_001A:  callvirt    System.IDisposable.Dispose
IL_001F:  endfinally  
IL_0020:  ldloc.2     // CS$1$0000
IL_0021:  ret
```

If it *matters* that your service *not* be disposed of before accessing the property (say in the context of NHibernate lazily loaded collections) then the order definitely matters. If it doesn't matter, then the biggest question should be what you and your team care about most. If you don't mind mixing and matching `using` calls so some have braces and some don't, then go ahead with what you have.

*Possibly* what might be something to consider is order of exception handling if accessing `WhoAmIResponse.UserId` has side effects. *If* the `Dispose` call on your service throws an exception, in your original code (`IsServerReachableOutsideUsingScope`) it will never have accessed your property and thus never executed its side effects. In the second block of code (`IsServerReachableWithinUsingScope`), it will have accessed and executed side effects of using the `UserId` property, *then* run the `Dispose` which throws an exception.

These are fairly rare cases (EDIT: and it should be noted that both get-access side effects and `Dispose()` throwing exceptions are considered bad practices), and I would suggest *if* it is the case here, then you should consider these for correctness. If these are non-issues (no side effects and do not care about order of access/disposal) then use what you and your team feel is more maintainable/readable in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

The `using` statement must include the declaration of the object that is supposed to be disposed when the statement terminates. Your code is correct as long as `OrganizationServiceProxy` implements `IDisposable` and `WhoAmIResponse` does not.

In case of doubt, it is normally useful to rewrite the using block as a try-finally block:

```
OrganizationServiceProxy service = GetService();
try {
   whoAmI = service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest()) as WhoAmIResponse;
} finally {
    service.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to write the `try/finally` equivalent block. If an exception is thrown on the thread _before_ it enters the `try` block, it will never dispose of the service. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2732078/1269654

Comment: It actually doesn't matter for correctness whether `WhoAmIResponse` implements `IDisposable` or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice for the scope of any `using` statement to be as small as practical.  So long as the objects returned by your `OrganizationServiceProxy` aren't disposed of when it runs the `Dispose` method, the indicated scope is perfectly acceptable.