# iDisposable object with using block and try/catch

Tags: c#

If I write code like this:

```
try
{
    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {

    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

And an exception is thrown by the StreamReader object (thus getting to the catch), does the using block finish correctly and dispose? Or do I need to wrap the content of the using block in a try instead?

Want to make sure I clean up appropriately.

Comment: Ah sorry :( I didn't see that one...

Comment: jon answers this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2732078/1657476

Answer (score 0):

> > does the using block finish correctly and dispose?

Yes. If `GetResponseStream` threw an exception, though, then there would be nothing to dispose because you haven't yet initialized the `StreamReader`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Object is disposed as soon as control goes out of using block.

Answer (score 0):

yes. `using` statement is interpreted like `try ... finally`.

Let's see an example:

```
using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f)) 
{
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
}
```

The code example earlier expands to the following code at compile time (note the extra curly braces to create the limited scope for the object):

For example:

```
Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
  try
  {
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
  }
  finally
  {
   if (font1 != null)
     ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();
  }
}
```

To learn about using statement, please, [see this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).